# C programming teams randomise

Tags: c, arrays, random, assign

i have a c program where I have an array of teams and teams shall be divided into 4 groups (groupA, groupB, groupC, groupD) with each group consisting of 4 teams. The team shall be placed in the group randomly. The error that the program is giving me is "Error type char[4] is not assignable" Thanks a lot :)

Here is the coding:

```
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char teams[20][17] = {
       "Germany", "Spain", "France", "Brazil", 
       "Italy", "Argentina", "USA","Uruguay", 
       "Hungry", "England", "Portugal", "Sweden", 
       "Netherlands", "Poland", "Mexico", "Croatia"
    };

char groupA[20][4];
char groupB[20][4];
char groupC[20][4];
char groupD[20][4];
char s[20];

int gA = 0 ,gB = 0 , gC = 0 , gD = 0;
int r , i;
int ok = 0;


for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    do{
        ok=0;
        printf("group = %s and team is %s", s,teams[i]);
        if(s==0 && gA<4){ //Group A
            groupA[gA]= teams[i];
            gA++;
            ok=1;
        }

       if(s==1 && gB<4){ //Group B
            groupB[gB]= teams[i];
            gB++;
            ok=1;
        }
        if(s==2 && gC<4){ //Group C
            groupC[gC]= teams[i];
            gC++;
            ok=1;
        }
        if(s==3 && gD<4){ //Group D
            groupD[gD]= teams[i];
            gD++;
            ok=1;
        }
    } while (!ok);
}   

for(i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
    printf("%.15s\t\t%.15s\t\t%.15s\t\t%.15s\n",
      groupA[i],
      groupB[i],
      groupC[i],
      groupD[i]
    );
}
```

Comment: Use `strcpy` to copy a string.

Comment: You don't have enough room in your array to hold the strings. `groupA` is an array of 20 elements, each of which is of type `char[4]`, which can only hold a string of length 3 (+1 for the terminating `'\0'`).

Comment: Besides he is comparing pointer to integer  in the if block !!

Comment: I don't know, I think I messed it all up. Now the strcpy is working, but the program is not. Sorry but I am still a beginner.. @Meninx

Comment: The while (!ok) is not working, since the loop is going on forever

Comment: you need to expand the size of strings to at least `12` characters ( `char groupD[20][12];`) and correct the comparison !  what do you mean by `s==0`  ?

Comment: but the [4] is to show how many words are in the array, if i'm not mistaken

Comment: the s==0 i really don't know i found it from a website and tried it hehe

Comment: okay let's ignore the link what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Oh thanks you're so nice for helping me :)

I want to randomise the teams and put them into 4 groups each containing 4 teams.

Comment: I think it will be a little bit difficult for you to do it especially as you are a beginner ! try to start with your own code and then you can post it when you find yourself blocked ! Stackoverflow is made for that reason ! Good Luck ! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change every line

```
groupX[gX]=teams[i];
```

where X is A or B etc

to

```
strcpy(groupB[gB],teams[i]);
```

The problem is that you cannot assign strings (by strings I mean array of chars) in C by using the operator `=` 
you need to use functions like `memcpy()` or `strcpy()`

The code you have written above still need to be fixed. Here is a commented code which can fits to your needs !

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
//important if you want to get different result in every execution (change the seed)
    srand(time(NULL));
//this is the list of all the teams
    char teams[16][12] = {"Germany" , "Spain" , "France" , "Brazil" , "Italy" , "Argentina" , "USA" ,"Uruguay" , "Hungry" ,"England" , "Portugal" , "Sweden" , "Netherlands" , "Poland" , "Mexico" , "Croatia"};

//each group will hold 4 teams each one
    char groupA[4][12];
    char groupB[4][12];
    char groupC[4][12];
    char groupD[4][12];

//the array s contain the name of each group only for print
    char s[4]= {'A','B','C','D'};
//the gX variables are the number of team of each group during the draw
    int gA = 0 ,gB = 0 , gC = 0 , gD = 0;
//the r is the random number representing the group on which every team will be
    int r , i;
    int ok = 0;

    printf("The World CUP Group Draw \n");
    printf(" **************************** \n");
    //this for loop is for the draw of groups
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        //when ok is zero that means the team is still without group
        ok=0;
        do
        {
            //we use the rand() in order to get a random number
            r=(rand()%4);

            if(r==0 && gA<4)  //Group A
            {
                printf("group = %c and team is %s\n", s[r],teams[i]);
                strcpy(groupA[gA],teams[i]);
                gA++;
                ok=1;
            }

            if(r==1 && gB<4)  //Group B
            {
                printf("group = %c and team is %s\n", s[r],teams[i]);
                strcpy(groupB[gB],teams[i]);
                gB++;
                ok=1;
            }
            if(r==2 && gC<4)  //Group C
            {
                printf("group = %c and team is %s\n", s[r],teams[i]);
                strcpy(groupC[gC],teams[i]);
                gC++;
                ok=1;
            }
            if(r==3 && gD<4)  //Group D
            {
                printf("group = %c and team is %s\n", s[r],teams[i]);
                strcpy(groupD[gD],teams[i]);
                gD++;
                ok=1;
            }

        }
        while (ok==0);
    }

//print the final result of the draw
    printf("\n%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n","GroupA","GroupB","GroupC","GroupD");
    printf("\n%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n","______","______","______","______");
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n",groupA[i],groupB[i],groupC[i],groupD[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @iharob because I know you are faster too !! ;)

Comment: I think he still need to correct the code to make it work ! anyway thanks for both of you !!

Comment: The  most important is that you need to understand how it works ! ;) Good Luck and keep learning !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strcpy()`, arrays are not assignable.